# Why a user with 1 reputation can post a comment?

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I saw in this question: [How do I backup a site when it weights is more than 200MB and host can't do it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/183716/28275) that the user [Nathan Follmer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/55216/nathan-follmer?tab=topactivity) post a comment in the question, but the user have 1 reputation. And the comment begin with:

> I can't comment yet, ...

But the comment is posted

[image]

It is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the answer that user wrote in a comment. We don't normally convert answers given from new users in comments, but since the OP answered, I did it.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: It's funny, the user says: 'I can't comment' but the comment is posted ;-)

Comment: Like the answer the systems must check this as migrated from a answer